# In Crystal, how to count per line item not per qty in an order?

Tags: crystal-reports

In Sap Crystal, I am looking for a better option to have the formula to count the # of items per line. (not per workorder)

Example, I have one Work Order# with 2 different items called Eton and Davina.
If I want to print the report, I would like to see that it is counting the # per product not as an order.

My code is:

```
WhilePrintingRecords; NumberVar ItemCount := ItemCount + 1;
```

`ToText(ItemCount, "0") & "/" & ToText(Count({rpt_PackingSlip.LabelQTY}, {rpt_PackingSlip.WorkOrderNo}),0,"")`

Crystal Report Design:

[image]

Current View:
[image]

Current Output:

If you can see, it is counting as 1/2 and 2/2, but my desired output should be 1/1 and 1/1 because it should be counting per product.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to show the crystal report design... looks like problem of grouping

Comment: @Siva, I've now edited it and include the Crystal Report Design.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this:

For numerator take running total count and reset for every record

For denominator take distinct count of work order

this should work

Comment: when you say take the numerator and reset every record, do you have code for that?WhilePrintingRecords; NumberVar ItemCount := ItemCount + 1;
ToText(ItemCount, "0") & "/" & ToText(Count({rpt_PackingSlip.LabelQTY}, {rpt_PackingSlip.WorkOrderNo}),0,"")

Comment: No I mean running total not formula field.. running total is a different concept